# jQuery .html() does not copy contents of textareas or inputs

Tags: jquery, input, textarea

I'm trying to copy the contents of an element using `elem.html()` but it's not including the contents of `inputs` or `textareas`.

Here's an example (try writting in the boxes then click "Copy"): http://jsfiddle.net/gAMmr/2/

Is there a way of copying all info?

These are the approaches I have tried so far:

- `elem.clone()` - not suitable for my task because it copies the
  element itself
- `elem.children().clone()` - misses out text nodes
- `elem.contents().clone()` - doesn't include the textarea contents

EDIT:  The results seem to be different in each browser.  I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Strangely enough, it seems to copy the contents just fine in IE8.

Comment: Do you need a string (HTML source code) or a *NodeList* (an array of DOM nodes)?

Comment: @Nick Yes, it appears that `$( textarea ).clone()` doesn't include the text from the original TEXTAREA element. I'll investigate...

Comment: @Nick Bug ticket is here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3016 It seems that there's still no solution to this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("#2").html($("#1").html());
    $("#1").find("input").each(function(idx) {
        $("#2").find("input").eq(idx).val($(this).val());
    });
    $("#1").find("textarea").each(function(idx) {
        $("#2").find("textarea").eq(idx).val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gAMmr/5/

Comment: @mblase I **strongly recommend against** `$("#2").html($("#1").html())`. Do this instead: `$('#1').contents().clone().appendTo('#2');`

Comment: @Nick `$("#2").html($("#1").html())` - this will serialize (stingify) the *NodeList* that represents the children of `#1`, only to parse that HTML string back into a *NodeList* in order to attach those nodes to the `#2` element. This process can be compared to having a digital signal converted to an analog signal, and than back to a digital signal. You don't wan to do that. To avoid serialization / deserialization, clone the elements.

Comment: @mblase No, that's not the reason. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392930/why-should-y-innerhtml-x-innerhtml-be-avoided) why it should be avoided.

Comment: Sime: I like how you went to ask all of SO how to contradict me. :-)

Comment: is the `clone()` still not fixed in jQuery? I don't understand https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3016

Answer (score 3):

As `Šime Vidas` pointed out earlier, [this is a 4-year old bug which hasn't been corrected](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3016), though a fix exists which is quite simple to apply:

-Download [jquery.fix.clone.js](https://raw.github.com/spencertipping/jquery.fix.clone/master/jquery.fix.clone.js)
-Include it in your page: `<script src='path/to/jquery.fix.clone.js'></script>`

From then on cloned `textarea` elements should include the text of their source (note: you need to use the `.clone()` method to create your new `textarea`, not `.html()`).

Answer (score 2):

Inputs don't contain HTML, they have `values`. Use `.val()` for form elements.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the type of the element you're trying to grab the inner text from and if it's an `input` or `textarea` use `$.text()` instead of `$.html()`