# Replace innerHTML of all divs with same class

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the innerHTML of all divs with class "count" with: items1.innerHTML.

How can I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't do anything with innerHTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392930/why-should-y-innerhtml-x-innerhtml-be-avoided

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var items = document.getElementById( 'items' ),
    divs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'count' );

[].slice.call( divs ).forEach(function ( div ) {
    div.innerHTML = items.innerHTML;
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/MGqGe/

I use this `[].slice.call( divs )` to transform the *NodeList* into a regular array, so that I can call the `forEach` method on it.

Btw, [careful with innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392930/why-should-y-innerhtml-x-innerhtml-be-avoided). I personally would use a library (like jQuery) to clone the contents instead.

Comment: +1 for a straight JavaScript answer, but it should check for getElementsByClassName existence if used.

Comment: @kinakuta `getElementsByClassName` and `forEach` aren't implemented in IE8. If the OP requires a cross-browser solution, he should use a library. If support for IE8 is not required, use my code.

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` and you'll gain IE8 support as long as you get rid of the `.slice` conversion to Array and the `forEach`.

Comment: @patrick If support for IE8 were required (hypothetically speaking), one could have a `ie8.js` file (pushed to IE8 via conditional comments) which would contain manual implementations of `getElementsByClassName`, `forEach`, etc. just for IE8. That way  those methods could still be used (despite IE8). As for the slice hack, it would probably be more reasonable to have a `toArray` utility function for that anyway (which would then do it the "slow way" by manually copying the references of all indexes).

Answer (score 12):

you can do this by jQuery this way

```
$("div.count").html("new content");
```

Comment: A more efficient selector is $('div.count') - as it relies on the fast DOM operation 'getElementsByTagName' to only fetch divs as a starting point.

Comment: @Beejamin And it does what the OP asked ("all divs with class 'count'"). Instead of possibly selecting extra elements.