# put content of div1 into div2 onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs as follows:

```
<div id='div1'>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>

<div id='div2'>

</div>

<a id='test' href='javascript:void()'>Click me to fill in div2</a>
```

I have been wondering what should be the best way to fill in div2 with the content of div1 onclick using jquery in order to have

```
<div id='div1'>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append a clone of the contents of `$("#div1")` to `$("#div2")` using [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents), [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone), and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append):

```
$("#div2").append($("#div1").contents().clone());
```

Comment: Why would you not do the simpler `$('#div2').html($('#div1').html());`?

Comment: @Floyd - See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7392930/361684) for a discussion on the merits of direct dom manipulation versus innerHTML manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that question. Helped put things into the right perspective!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than resorting to serialising to HTML and then applying that to the other element, as [Andy's answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654606/put-content-of-div1-into-div2-onclick-event/7654623#7654623), it would be nicer to clone the nodes.

```
$('#test').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#div1').contents().clone(true).appendTo('#div2');
});
```

This has the advantage that any data or events on the elements cloned will continue to exist on the new elements. Since I've used `e.preventDefault()`, you can also lose the `javascript:void` bit of your code, because the link's default action has been prevented.

See the jQuery API:

- [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents)
- [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone)
- [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo)
- [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div2').html($('#div1').html());
```