# Use .get(0) or .html() to return HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So as far as I can tell, if I have

```
<div id="thing">OMG there's awesome stuff in here</div>
```

and need to plant that html somewhere else, I have the option of using:
`$('#thing').html();` or `$('#thing').get(0);`

Is there a greater internet standard in using one or the other? They do the exact same thing, right?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to remove that element from its parent node, then append it elsewhere in the DOM tree, correct?

Comment: `.html()` serializes a DOM structure, `get(0)` retrieves a DOM reference. As you can see, those two do completely different things. Btw [DOM serialization should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392930/why-should-y-innerhtml-x-innerhtml-be-avoided).

Answer (score 16):

> They do the exact same thing, right?

Wrong. The `html` method returns the *contents* of the selected element, as a string. The `get` method returns the element itself, as an object. For example, we have this element:

```
<div id="example">
    <span>A child element</span>
</div>
```

The methods would return the following:

```
console.log($("#example").html()); //Prints "<span>A child element</span>"
console.log($("#example").get(0)); //Prints an object
```

You can try that for yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4HDkW/).

Answer (score 8):

`.get(0)` will give you the first element in the jquery object, not the HTML within that.  You would then need to get the html.  If you're using jquery, use jquery.  I see no reason not to use `.html()`.

Comment: I'm an idiot, .html() gets you the innerHTML, .get(0) gets you the html element in its entirety.

Comment: @JamesMontagne you said, "If you're using jquery, use jquery. I see no reason not to use `.html()`".  But `.html() _is_ jQuery and definitely has its uses. We really don't know what the OP wants here.

Comment: @jaa Yes I did... what I meant was use `.html`, why would you use `get` and get the dom element.  I wasn't saying don't use `.html`.  After re-reading the question, I had taken "some html" to mean the actual html and not the element, but it very well could have been a misuse of terms and he could want to move the dom element, in which case probably neither should be used.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Sorry, I misread you to say, "I see NO REASON to use .html()." Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

These two things do close to the same thing (note the addition of `.innerHTML` to what you had in your question):

```
$('#thing').html();

$('#thing').get(0).innerHTML;
```

The first creates a jQuery object, then calls the .html() method on it (which in turns gets the HTML from the `.innerHTML` property).

The second creates a jQuery object, then gets the first DOM element out of it and gets the innerHTML property from it.

In general, if you already have a jQuery object, then use `.html()`.  If you already have a DOM object, then use `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to duplicate some elements, do *not* use `html`. It is a very inefficient way of cloning elements. There is a much better way, called [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone) (funnily enough):

```
$('#thing').clone(true).removeProp('id').appendTo('#someOtherElement');
```

Note that I am removing the `id` property, as it must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not do the exact same thing.

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) returns HTML string representing the DOM structure *inside* the element contained within the jQuery collection object: "OMG there's awesome stuff in here".

[`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the first DOM element object from the collection, in this case a DOM node of tag-type `DIV` with ID "thing" and child text-node with value "OMG there's awesome stuff in here"

Answer (score 0):

I've only used .html() and I work for a firm. I have never seen .get(0) used for anything like this

Answer (score 0):

They are fairly different.  The `get` method returns a DOM element while `html()` returns a string.  Here it looks like you want the HTML so use `html()`

Answer (score 0):

These two methods are different

`get()` Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object. See:
http://api.jquery.com/get/

`html()` Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements. See:
http://api.jquery.com/html/