# using jquery, how can i speed up appending a list onto a selector

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, performance, append

i have the following code which seems very slow and I wanted to see if there was any other way of dumping out these arrays any faster.

```
$.get("/MyController/GetDates?month=1&year=2011", function (data) {

        $.each(data.VacationEvents, function (index, value) {
            $("#vacationDates").append('<p>' + value.Date + '</p>');
        });
        $.each(data.CalendarEvents, function (index, value) {
            $("#calendarDates").append('<p>' + value.Date + '</p>');
        });
        $.each(data.ReleaseEvents, function (index, value) {
            $("#releasenDates").append('<p>' + value.Date + '</p>');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an array and then append that once to the element. I suspect it's so slow because for every append you have to update the DOM, so this way you'd only update the DOM 3 times.

```
var dates = [];
$.each(data.VacationEvents, function (index, value) {
     dates.push('<p>' + value.Date + '</p>');
});
$("#vacationDates").append(dates.join(''));
```

Also if you create a 2 dimensional array you could store the actual date, as well as the text, and then if you also hold a reference to the date array you can then easily allow the user to sort by date on the client side.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you modify connected DOM nodes it will force browser to reflow the document. See #9 from [10 Javascript Performance Boosting Tips](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas).

Solution:

- Create a `innerHTML` variable that will contain generated HTML.
- Append HTML to it inside the `.each()`.
- Append `innerHTML` to `#vacationDates`.
- Do the same for `#calendarDates` and `#releasenDates`.

  ```
  // ...
  var innerHTML = "";
  $.each(data.VacationEvents, function (index, value) {
     innerHTML += '<p>' + value.Date + '</p>';
  });
  $("#vacationDates").append(innerHTML);
  // ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending textual html, create the elements. The short answer is that this prevents your browser from having to parse text into HTML. The longer [answer can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393126/979401).

Replace

```
$.each(data.VacationEvents, function (index, value) {
    $("#vacationDates").append('<p>' + value.Date + '</p>');
});
```

with

```
$.each(data.VacationEvents, function (index, value) {
    vacation_date = document.createElement('p');
    vacation_date.innerHTML = value.Date; /* it pains me to do this */
    $("#vacationDates".append(vacation_date);
});
```

Comment: `innerText` does not work in Firefox; must use `textContent` there.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, changing.

Comment: `textContent` doesn't work in IE8 and lower. Must use `innerText` there. ;)

Comment: yeah, but ♫I'm too sexy for IE♫.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by 'faster'? just more condensed or less lines of code? Maybe something like this?

```
$.get("/MyController/GetDates?month=1&year=2011", function (data) {

    var myData = ['Vacation','Calendar','Release'];
    for(var i=0; i<myData.length; i++) {
        $.each(data[myData[i]], function(index, value) {
            $("#" + myData[i] + "Dates").append('<p>' + value.Date + '</p>');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the OP means "code that executes faster," not "code which is more concise."

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL It was kind of unclear, so I wasn't sure. Well, any solution provided by someone else could also be combined with this.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to minimize DOM operations, so instead of `.append()`ing inside the loop, build up the set of elements and then append them. It's also faster to avoid looping functions, and just use a `for` loop. Something like this:

```
$.get("/MyController/GetDates?month=1&year=2011", function (data) {

    var vacationEvents = data.VacationEvents;
        $newVacations = $();

    for (var i=0; i<vacationEvents.length; i++) {
        $newVacations.add($('<p></p>', {text: vacationEvents[i].Date}));
    }

    $newVacations.appendTo("#vacationDates");

    // etc
});
```

Comment: The other suggested variations on this method may be faster, but the idea is the same.