# How can I clone everything in a div without cloning the outer div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use `jQuery.clone()`  but I only want to copy the inner elements, not the element itself. If needed I can wrap the contents but I was hoping to find another way to just clone the inner html.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried .children().clone()?

Comment: @Guillaume86 http://stackoverflow.com/q/7392930

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, you can use `.children().clone()`

http://jsfiddle.net/pR6ve/1

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) to get all the child nodes (and their descendants):

```
$('#foo').contents().clone(true).appendTo('#bar');
```

Comment: yet another `$("#foo").clone(true).unwrap().appendTo("#bar");`

Comment: @AndreasAL No, because that would attempt to unwrap the clone of `#foo`, which is impossible because it doesn't have a parent element. You'd have to do `.clone(true).contents().unwrap()`.