# Extracting HTML The Right Way

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, innerhtml

Strange behavior I noticed. I have a hidden (display:'none') HTML on a page. Then I create a tooltip and extract some data from that hidden HTML into this tooltip, as an example, this way:

```
 $('#tooltip').html( $('#hiddenElement').html() );
```

If I modify class name within that hidden html (which is now inside of tooltip) that class name always remains original (unchanged) when it is accessed through DOM:

```
 alert($('#hiddenElement .element').hasClass('some-class');
```

So it looks like extracting HTML does not work well as if you use a copy of it which does not reflect DOM. Can anyone explain what really happens? I do not have a test case. Hopefully someone is familiar with what I describe. Thanks

Comment: You might want to read this: [Why should y.innerHTML = x.innerHTML; be avoided?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392930/why-should-y-innerhtml-x-innerhtml-be-avoided)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#hiddenElement').html()` returns the `innerHtml` of `#hiddenElement` as one single string.

Inserting that string into `$('#tooltip').html( /*here*/ );` will cause jQuery to detect that you've given a string, and therefore it will continue and parse the string to new `HtmlElement`'s. This means you've effectively created a clone from the contents of `#hiddenElement`, in a way that costs a lot more time than [jQuery.fn.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

If you do not want to create clones, you could instead use [`jQuery.fn.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
$('#tooltip').html( $('#hiddenElement').contents() );
```

However, as this does not *clone* the contents, it will *move* them to a new location, and therefore the content will no longer be in the `#hiddenElement`.

As far as I know, there is no way for a single DOM-node to be in two parent nodes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#tooltip').html( $('#hiddenElement').html() );` this line will replace `#tooltip`'s content by `#hiddenElement`'s content but `#hiddenElement` remains unchanged.

When you modify anything inside `#hiddenElement` it will be just for this element. There is no reference to the content which was copied in the earlier line so there will be no change in `#tooltip`'s content when you modify `#hiddenElement`'s content.

Instead of `html` method you should use `append` method if you want to move content from one element to another.

Comment: If I have an element with ID inside of the copied content, that element cannot be accessed - only original element is accessed with original properties. That's my problem. And strangely, there are no 2 elements of the same ID...

Comment: You should try to avoid same id for multiple elements. In that case jQuery will select only one element which it matches first. But if you specify the context it should search within that context.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#hiddenElement').html()` fetchs the HTML markup under hiddenElement div and the hiddenElement div itself is not included in it.

Hence, you can use something like `$('#tooltip .element')` to change the class

Comment: This helped me access my lost element. Thanks.