# jquery clone form element and insert it in the form

Tags: jquery, forms, insert, clone

Hy, my problem is this http://jsfiddle.net/VZ2MK/1/

```
(function(){

    var input = $('.test').clone();

    $('a.add_input').on('click', function(e){

        $(this).before(input);

        e.preventDefault();

    });

})();
```

I need to add dynamically some parts of a form, and i thought i'll clone it and then add it.
And it worked for the first time, but if i want to add more than once, it stops, i mean it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should clone it by every click. The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ2MK/10/).

```
var input = $('.test');

$('a.add_input').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).before(input.clone());

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `before` detatches the element from where it currently is, before inserting it before the selected element. You need to do the clone each time, rather than doing it once:

```
(function(){
    $('a.add_input').on('click', function(e){
        var input = $('.test').last().clone();    

        $(this).before(input);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
})();
```

Your original code inserted the clone the first time, but on subsequent occasions removed it before re-adding it in exactly the same place.

Note that I am only cloning the `last` of the `$('.test')` items to avoid adding 1 the first time, 2 the second time, 4 the third time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning every click works:

```
(function(){
    $('a.add_input').on('click', function(e){
var input = $('.test').clone();
        $(this).before(input);

        e.preventDefault();

    });  
})();
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/VZ2MK/4/

But I didn't use `clone()`

```
 (function(){
     input = $('.test').html();   
     $('a.add_input').click(function(e){   
         $(this).before('<div>' + input + '</div>');       
         e.preventDefault();      
     });   
 })();
```

Comment: This is a bad answer. It destroys any data or event handlers stored on the elements. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7393126/417562) to another question explains why this is a bad technique.

Comment: Maybe the op was looking for this instead.. ?