# jQuery load 'POST' error

Tags: jquery, html

I am just trying to load the content of one div into another onClick, but i get an error requesting i use the POST request,

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     $('#slide1').load('#slide2');
});
```

half working example at http://jsfiddle.net/9hnZx/

Still new to the whole jQuery front so please be patient if this is a stupid question! Thanks!

edit. Thanks to all who answered, really helped, except the example i gave is working in jsfiddle but i cant get working in the website where it is required,
http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/j3mobile/
anyone got any clues? jQuery is loading just fine!

Comment: `load` doesn't do what you think it does, see: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers suggest copying the HTML of one element to another.  This is a bad idea, for the reasons illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392930/why-should-y-innerhtml-x-innerhtml-be-avoided/7393126#7393126).  Instead, copy the DOM elements:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#slide1').html($('#slide2').contents());
});
```

For documentation on this, see the API reference pages for [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) and [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#slide1').html($('#slide2').html());
});
```

Comment: this works in the jsfiddle example but when i put it into my website it doesnt work for some reason, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

try instead

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
         $('#slide1').html($('#slide2').html());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Code

```
$("#button").click(function(){
         //first get the send div text
        var secondDiv = $("#slide2").text();
        var firstDiv = $("#slide1").text();
         // slide 1 value

         $('#slide2').text(secondDiv+" "+firstDiv);
    });
```

Comment: surely this will only put text from one div into another? when used in its intended application it will be taking lots more content other than just text.